# What is a Super Duper Demon Battle?

Tags: prinny-2

Sometimes when starting a boss fight (I saw it with the Phantom Thief and Bloomin' Mustard) the words "Super Duper Demon Battle" show up before the fight and Prinny responds "What the *hell*?"

What does this message mean? It doesn't normally show up before bosses, just a rare few. I *have* noticed the boss fights it shows up for are *even more* extremely difficult but that's all.

Comment: I think it shows up whenever you are fight "special" notable characters (major and minor) from the Disgaea games ('cept D4), like Prinny Laharl, Prinny Baal, etc... *Dood*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no special meaning.** The message means exactly what it says. The *battle* will be against a *demon* of *super duper* quality. Simply put, **the fight is going to suck hard** and the likelihood of dying in one hit is high for many of them. As Krazer said, these are usually notable characters.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. Do you know how to beat the phantom theif dood? That's my next Q